# Parse local XML file in Android

Tags: xml, android

How can I parse my local XML file located in my android project (inside res/XML folder) and want to get the values in that file.

Comment: You can check this link too
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9915219/parse-a-local-xml-file-and-store-in-sqlite-database-in-android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702729/store-parsed-xml-data-to-sqlite-android check this too.it may help you

Answer (score 10):

To access XML resources stored in `res/xml`, call [`getResources().getXml()`](http://file:///opt/android-sdk-linux_x86-1.5_r3/docs/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getXml(int)) from any `Activity` or other `Context`. You need to supply to `getXml()` the ID of the XML to load (`R.xml.myfile`).

Comment: The getXml() method automatically returns you an XmlResourceParser implementation instance, so you can directly pass it to XmlPullParser and start parsing your data.

Answer (score 4):

to read your xml add code as shown below

```
XmlResourceParser myxml = mContext.getResources().getXml(R.xml.MyXml);
//MyXml.xml is name of our xml in newly created xml folder, mContext is the current context
// Alternatively use: XmlResourceParser myxml = getContext().getResources().getXml(R.xml.MyXml);

myxml.next();//Get next parse event
int eventType = myxml.getEventType(); //Get current xml event i.e., START_DOCUMENT etc.
```

and to get content of code add code shown below