# find and display element from the xml file with android

Tags: android, xml

I have an xml file:

```
      <elements>
      <element form="a">
      <name>azerty</name>
      </element>
      <elements>
      <element form="b">
      <name>qwerty</name></element></elements>
```

how can i find the name when i enter the form from an EditText or find the form when i enter the name?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're trying to parse a file in `res/xml` you can use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372470/parse-local-xml-file-in-android).

The [XmlPullParser docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html) have a short example for parsing.

You'd want to read through your xml document, populating a map (or a bidirectional map). This map would allow you to do the lookup multiple times while only parsing the xml file once.