# How can I recreate a database with default values?

Tags: android

In my application, I want to delete my existing database and create a new one with default values. Default values can be inserted to the database from XML.

Does anyone have any idea on how to reuse a database?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using a SQLite database, to delete all the rows from all of your tables inside your database you can use db.execSQL() and heed the advice from this question [Drop all tables command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525512/):

> You can do it with the following **DANGEROUS** commands:
>
> ```
>  PRAGMA writable_schema = 1;
>  delete from sqlite_master where type = 'table';
>  PRAGMA writable_schema = 0;
> ```
>
> you then want to recover the deleted space with
>
> ```
>  VACUUM
> ```
>
> and a good test to make sure everything is ok
>
> ```
>  PRAGMA INTEGRITY_CHECK;
> ```

If you haven't written a way to read your XML data yet, this is excellent reading: [Store parsed xml data to sqlite ? Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702729/store-parsed-xml-data-to-sqlite-android)

Answer (score 0):

Well basically that's not an Android specific question.

Firstly when do you want to recreate the database with default values and how to trigget it.

- In an UI event like button click etc?
- Or when you start/stop or destroy your activity?

In any cases you need to drop the database and recreate the whole structure (tables,relationships etc.) again.