# Parse a local XML file and store in sqlite database in Android

Tags: android, xml, sqlite

I would like anybody to show me the CODE on how to read a local xml file (maths.xml) and parse it with a parser and then store the information obtained into a sqllite database (maths.db) and after that how to query the database for a given search word example "101"

for example the maths.xml is as follows

```
<maths>

<mathametician>
<id>101</id>
<name>kurt</name>
<age>75</age>
</mathametician>

<mathametician>
<id>102</id>
<name>david</name>
<age>62</age>
</mathametician>

</maths>
```

Answer (score 0):

put your xml file into asset folder and you can get xml in form of input stream

```
InputStream raw = context.getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(
                    "maths.xml");
```

you can parse this xml using different parser like SAX,Dom here is small code of dom parsee

```
Document dom = builder.parse(raw);
Element root = dom.getDocumentElement()
NodeList mathametician = root.getElementsByTagName("mathametician");
```

for (int i = 0; i < mathametician.getLength(); i++)

and insert your data to db as you  got tag from xml

Comment: thanks a lot.. could you also show how to insert the data to the db.. i am new to all this

Comment: Build your modle which has get-set method and insert it nto database using this method
              `public long insertMathdata(MethModel model) {
      ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
      values.put(id, model.getId());
      values.put(name, model.getName);
      values.put(age, model.getAge);
      return myDataBase.insert(tablename, null, values);
     }`