# Read xml file from Android Asset folder

Tags: android, xml, android-assets

I'm trying to read the same file "*xmlfile.xml*" from the **assets** folder and also another copy from the SD card **sdcard/download/**.

I can Read from SD Card:

- unfile Return **True**
- Esite Return **True**

I can't not Read from Assets folder:

- unfile Return **False**
- Esite Return **False**

---

This code il NOT Working

```
        File source = new File("file:///android_asset/xmlfile.xml");
        boolean unfile = source.isFile();
        boolean Esiste = source.exists();

        try
        {
          // todo
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

---

This code il Working

```
        File source = new File("/sdcard/" + "download" + "/" + "xmlfile.xml");
        boolean unfile = source.isFile();
        boolean Esiste = source.exists();

        try
        {
          // todo
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

someone can explain me how can I read the file from the Assets folder.

thanks
marco

Comment: see ans given by me at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372470/parse-local-xml-file-in-android/8413361#8413361

Answer (score 12):

To open an asset you'd need the following piece of code:

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open("xmlfile.xml")
```

Answer (score 7):

Use this function

```
// Converting given XML file name to String form
String mOutputText = getxml("yourxml.xml");

/**
 * Function used to fetch an XML file from assets folder
 * @param fileName - XML file name to convert it to String
 * @return - return XML in String form
 */
private String getXml(String fileName) {
    String xmlString = null;
    AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
    try {
        InputStream is = am.open(fileName);
        int length = is.available();
        byte[] data = new byte[length];
        is.read(data);
        xmlString = new String(data);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return xmlString;
}
```

Comment: For File I meant the Class [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html)

Comment: replace 
InputStream is = am.open(path);
with
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(File)
i think it may help

Answer (score 1):

I found it easier to do the following:

```
val xmlStream = context.resources.getXml(R.xml.example)
```

I believe this is a subset of XmlPullParser, but it has worked well enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
    try 
    {
        AssetManager aManager = Class.getAssets();
        InputStream iStream = aManager.open("file.xml");
        int length = iStream.available();
        byte[] data = new byte[length];
        iStream.read(data);
        assetString = new String(data).toString();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will surely help you.
For reading a file form assets folder you need a `InputStream` Object.

*Syntax:*

```
InputStream yourobj=getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("Path to xml file");
```

*So the live code can be*:

```
InputStream in_s = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("www/application/app/client/controllers/data1.xml");
```

Here `data1.xml` is the file inside the path.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to get the value of a specific item inside the .xml you could use this:

```
object AssetUtils {

    fun readXmlItemByName(
        context: Context,
        assetFileName: String,
        itemName: String
    ): String? {
        try {
            // Open file stream from project asset folder
            val fileInputStream = context.assets.open(assetFileName)

            // Create buffer to stream file into
            val size = fileInputStream.available()
            val buffer = ByteArray(size)

            // Read stream into buffer
            fileInputStream.read(buffer)
            fileInputStream.close()

            // Write buffer to string
            val utf8: Charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8")
            val string = String(buffer, utf8)

            // Check lines for xml item name
            val xmlItemName = "\"" + itemName + "\""
            val lines = string.lines()
            lines.forEach {
                // Found parameterName in line
                if (it.contains(xmlItemName)) {
                    // Extract value
                    val value = it.substringAfter(">").substringBefore("</")

                    // Return value
                    if (value.isNotBlank()) {
                        return value
                    }
                }
            }

            return null
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("AssetsUtils", "readXmlParameter(): ${e.message}")
            return null
        }
    }

}
```